# Reference for the C methods used in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, methods, static-methods

Is there a good reference somewhere with all the C functions that can be used by default in iPhone development (I guess they lie in the Foundation framework)? I mean functions like:
arc4random(), cos(), sinf(), hypot(), sqrt(), sqrtf() etc...

They are so many considering their variations too (sin(), sinf()) and googling every single time is ineffective.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode/Help/Documentation

Then look in the Core Library. You may need to subscribe to one or more documentation sets first. Check that you search is not limited to Objective-C also.

Comment: The Apple documentation is pretty comprehensive

Comment: Cool I didn't check the Core Library. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for all of the math functions, they can be found in the header file

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/math.h
```

For more generic functions, in addition to the documentation, I often find it helpful to right-(or Control-)click on a function in my code and choose "Jump to Definition".  This takes you to the related header, which might also have similar functions and constants.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple iPhone OS Man Pages doc is the handiest guide for this kind of thing.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/

Unfortunately being HeaderDoc driven, there's no PDF version. I thought at one point Apple indexed these symbols in the Xcode docset API indexes, but they don't seem to be there now.

Good luck!